# Opening MS Word document in a Webservice runs for ever

Tags: vb.net, web-services, ms-word, office-interop

I a have web service which picks up a word file adds a table and saves as PDF. This works fine if run on a console app on the same server. But when I run from the Webservice it runs for ever it keeps on loading the word document and never comes back and the CPU usage bumps up to 100% . Below is the code it hang right at the Document.open() Line

```
    Dim wordDoc As Document
    Dim WrdApp As New Application

    WrdApp.Visible = False
    'Load document 'below is the line it never passes in the webservice 
    wordDoc = WrdApp.Documents.Open(strWordFilePath)
```

I have tried all the possibilities, changing the COM object etc; I think I am missing something stupid but unable to figure out what it is.

Comment: I suspect there might be a dialog hanging somewhere. Try to set `WrdApp.DisplayAlerts = 0` (0 is wdAlertsNone) before opening the document.

Comment: @DanL no it do not work out I  tried it too!